80s/90s SF: City is playing a virtual reality killing game
Its an old scifi movie i think from the 80s or 90s.  
It takes place in the future where most of the city is playing a virtual reality killing game.  They use devices that insert a needle into the brain via the ear.  
Every player tries to get past the 4-5 levels so they can meet "the angel".  One of the players (i think was the game developer) dies while playing and her mind/soul is stuck playing the game.  
The main character (male) tries to solve the murder (while also hacking the game to see the angel and have leizure time in a heavenly reality simulation) as portals open up around the city allowing the monsters to kill people and vanish when the portal signals are shut down.  
The CEO hacks the game and reformats the angel who then goes homicidal and starts shutting off the city's air supply.  The main character and a team of people go through the portal into the game itself to fight past players and monsters, eventually dying one by one as they get past the grim reaper at the end to fight the killer angel.  
In the end the main guy dies and is programmed into a heavenly environment by one of the ladies in the movie.  
I can't for the life of me remember the title.  

Welcome to Movies & TV! What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors?

Nirvana is a movie from 1997 that involves VR and a digital heaven.
According to Wikipedia, it also references "angels".
Unfortunately, it doesn't have the hero die in the end.

Darkdrive from 1997 has the VR element and the hero dying at the end and going to a digital heaven.  Not sure about the other elements as I saw only the last 10 minutes. 

just seen it, the vr looks almost right but other wise nothing matches.  thanks though.
